# reading data from bluetooth blood pressure monitor U80IH

Tags: node.js, bluetooth, monitor, gatt, pressure

I got a Bluetooth blood pressure monitor [U80IH](http://www.ebay.com/itm/231430845385) and trying to understand how I can read data from this device using noble npm module using GATT interface.

I run `scan` and `info` commands using `cylon-ble` and got this results....

Seller/manufacturer didn't provided GATT specification for this device.

Trying to see if someone can reverse engineer and find the way to start measuring process and read data.

> sudo node_modules/.bin/cylon-ble-info 8cde5263626e

```
peripheral with UUID 8cde5263626e found
  Local Name        = Bluetooth BP
  Service Data      = 
  Service UUIDs     = 

services and characteristics:
1800 (Generic Access)
  2a00 (Device Name)
    properties  read
    value       426c7565746f6f7468204250 | 'Bluetooth BP'
  2a01 (Appearance)
    properties  read
    value       8000 | ''
  2a04 (Peripheral Preferred Connection Parameters)
    properties  read
    value       060080000000800c | '
                                    '
180a (Device Information)
  2a29 (Manufacturer Name String)
    properties  read
    value       49535343 | 'ISSC'
  2a24 (Model Number String)
    properties  read
    value       425435303530 | 'BT5050'
  2a25 (Serial Number String)
    properties  read
    value       384344453532363336323645 | '8CDE5263626E'
  2a27 (Hardware Revision String)
    properties  read
    value       353035305f5350500000000000 | '5050_SPP'
  2a26 (Firmware Revision String)
    properties  read
    value       32303235303231 | '2025021'
  2a28 (Software Revision String)
    properties  read
    value       30303030 | '0000'
  2a23 (System ID)
    properties  read
    value       0000000000000000 | ''
  2a2a (IEEE 11073-20601 Regulatory Certification Data List)
    properties  read
    value       0001000400000000 | ''
49535343fe7d4ae58fa99fafd205e455
  495353436daa4d02abf619569aca69fe
    properties  read, write
    value       003600360000002a00 | '66*'
  49535343aca3481c91ecd85e28a60318
    properties  write, notify
fff0
  fff1
    properties  notify
  fff2
    properties  write
```